# GoLang: Check if item from Slice 1 contains in Slice 2. If it does, remove Slice 2

Tags: arrays, for-loop, go, slice

I have a string array: slice1 [][]string. 
I get the values I want using a for loop:

```
for _, i := range slice1 { //[string1 string2]
    fmt.Println("server: ", i[1]) //only want the second string in the array.
}
```

Now I have another string array: slice2 [][]string
I get its values using a for loop as well:

```
for _, value := range output { //
    fmt.Println(value) //Prints: [ 200K, 2, "a", 22, aa-d-2, sd , MatchingString, a ]
}
```

I want to iterate through slice1 and check if the string2 matches "MatchingString" in Slice2. If it does, don't print the value array.

I created a for loop again to do this but its not working:

```
for _, value := range slice2 {
    for _, i := range slice1 {
        if strings.Contains(value[0], i[1]) {
            //skip over
        } else {
            fmt.Println(value)
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a sample code: https://play.golang.org/p/KMVzB2jlbG
Any idea on how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide a sample code in Go Playground?

Comment: Here you go and let me know if you have any questions: https://play.golang.org/p/KMVzB2jlbG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you are trying to print all those subslices of `slice2` that have the property that none of the strings within are the second element of a slice in `slice1`. If so, you can obtain that through

```
Slice2Loop:
    for _, value := range slice2 {
        for _, slice2string := range value {
            for _, i := range slice1 {
                if slice2string == i[1] {
                    continue Slice2Loop
                }
            }
        }
        fmt.Println(value)
    }
```

Comment: yep you got it! Thanks!

Comment: Hi. I made some changes to my code and I was wondering if you could help with it. Here's the go-playground: https://play.golang.org/p/7LZqc6Yol3   Let me know if you have questions

Comment: @shishh03: That will be easier if you just open a new question where you spell out what you are trying to achieve, and what the current issue is.

Comment: sure, will do. Thanks!